# Autoindent JavaDoc for the return tag using Intellij IDEA 2016.2.4

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

How can I set my IDEA to autoindent the whole sentence for the `return` tags? The IDE only autoindents the first line but ignores the following ones. Therefore checkstyle points me to this line being indented not correctly.

When I use four tabs to indent the line the checkstyle message disappears but after I reformat code with Ctrl+Alt+L the tab chars are removed and I again get the same message. I didn't found any settings for the return tag in `File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > JavaDoc tab`.

Comment: Just had a look at our code formatter which is used in a quite wide base and that does the same reformatting. I would probably rather exclude the checkstyle rule which complains about this..

Comment: @hammerfest I dont't know why but wrapping the sentence into  `p` tags cause the message to disappear. Looks ugly, though but is the only workaround besides excluding the rule. Could you maybe point me to this rule? I only found `JavadocTagContinuationIndentation` but I'm afraid it'd also affect all other things in javadoc

Comment: You shouldn't be using tabs anyway. Use spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current IntelliJ-IDEA (2022.2) has a setting for this. I used it to successfully get rid of the CheckStyle error.
Under `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > JavaDoc` tab, the node `Other > Indent continuation lines`, just activate that CheckBox.